# How to display specific component based on URL in Angular 5?

Tags: angular, angular5

In my view *group-summary.component.html* I have:

```
<div class="row">
      <ng-container>
        <nol-apple-details *ngIf="isAppleRouteActivated" [someDetails]="detailsToShow" class="col-xs-12 col-md-12"></nol-apple-details>
        <nol-kiwi-details *ngIf="isKiwiRouteActivated" [someDetails]="detailsToShow" class="col-xs-12 col-md-12"></nol-kiwi-details>
      </ng-container>
</div>
```

As you can see which component will be displayed is determinate by simple flag in *GroupSummaryComponent*.

```
isAppleRouteActivated: boolean = this.router.url.indexOf("/category/apple") > -1;
isKiwiRouteActivated: boolean = this.router.url.indexOf("/category/kiwi") > -1;
```

IMO this solution isn't elegant and I think it's hack. Can anyone more experienced suggest a different solution to me? I was trying to use named outlet although it didn't work for me especially that I had no idea how to pass `someDetails`

And this is my routing:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: "groups", component: GroupListComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: "groups/:id/category", component: CategoryComponent },
    {
        path: "groups/:id/category", component: GroupSummaryComponent, children: [
            { path: "apple", loadChildren: "app/features/apple.module#AppleModule" },
            { path: "kiwi", loadChildren: "app/features/kiwi.module#KiwiModule" }
        ]
    }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [CanActivate](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) guard to redirect to the right route.

Implement CanActivate :

```
canActivate(): boolean {
        const isRoute1 = // here your test if this route must be used;
        if (!isRoute1) {
            this._router.navigate(['/route2']); // if not redirect to the other route
        }
        return isRoute1;
}
```

And use your guard in the route declaration :

```
{
        path: '/route1',
        canActivate: [YourCanActivateGuard],
        component: YourComponent
}
```

And the same for the second route.

Comment: Still I'm not sure how it suppose to help me?

Comment: Instead of using the ngIf, you can use a guard to redirect to the right path/component. Not what you're looking for ?

Comment: Yea but still you need to provide this route. That's what I wanted to avoid. Since if URL will change then it will be difficult to find it.